# Not able to use RSQLserver

Tags: sql-server, r

I am trying to use RSQLServer and first installed RSQLServer using R studio. then I am trying to use it like this.

```
library(RSQLServer)
library(DBI)
drv <- dbDriver("SqlServer")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, url = "Server=**MYSERVERURL;database=DBName;trusted_connection=yes;")
res <- dbSendQuery(conn, "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM test_table (NOLOCK)")
str(res)
```

But I am getting error everytime. Am I missing something? The Error is Object not found.? Do I need to configure any driver (probably jTDS) first? If yes, can anyone share steps to do that? Thanks.

Error text

```
> conn <- dbConnect(drv, url = "Server=**MYSERVERURL;database=DBName;trusted_connection=yes;")
Error in dbConnect(drv, url = "Server=**MYSERVERURL;database=DBName;trusted_connection=yes;") : 
  object 'drv' not found
> res <- dbSendQuery(conn, "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM test_table (NOLOCK)")
Error in dbSendQuery(conn, "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM test_table (NOLOCK)") : 
  object 'conn' not found
> str(res)
Error in str(res) : object 'res' not found
```

Note: name of table and database changed.

Comment: Please show us the error message, tell us your OS and whether you have installed the rClr package.

Comment: I am working on Windows Platform. basically I am trying to run some queries in R Studio and connecting to SQL Server. req is to fetch large amount of data using RSQLSerrver package, I am able to do so using RODBC.

Comment: Error in dbConnect(drv, url = ** my db string **, looks like connection is not created, No, I don't have rClr package installed.

Comment: I tried to install rClr and it returned--- Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘C:/Users/rkumar/Downloads/rClr_0.7-4.zip’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1). my windows is 64 bit

Comment: Sorry, my fault, RSQLServer is JDBC (= Java) based, not Microsoft .Net, so rClr ist not required.

Comment: Can you please add the exact error message to your question by editing it. Please show the R code line that causes the error as well as the **exact** error message (replace credentials and server names with dummy text). Otherwise it is just guessing for us. BTW Which JDBC driver did you install?

Comment: I have MS JDBC driver for SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
drv <- RSQLServer::SQLServer()
```

instead of

```
drv <- dbDriver("SqlServer")
```

You must have downloaded and installed the [jTDS driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).

For Windows authentication you have to install a DLL too:

> If you intend to use integrated security (Windows Authentication) to
>   authenticate your server session, you will need to download jTDS and
>   copy the native single sign on library (ntlmauth.dll) to any
>   location on your system’s PATH (e.g. Sys.getenv("PATH") ).

Source: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLServer/RSQLServer.pdf

---

Your JDBC connection string looks strange, please make sure your JDBC connection string is correct.

If you are using the jTDS driver the connection string syntax is
different from the JDBC driver of Microsoft

The jTDS syntax is specified here:

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat

```
jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]]
```

where  is "sqlserver".

---

The Microsoft JDBC syntax is specified here but I think it does not work because **[RSQLServer  is based on the cross-platform jTDS JDBC driver](https://github.com/imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer)**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx

Example:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Replace the "localhost" part with the IP address or server name like "myServer.honey.moon.com", in case of a non-standard IP port (not 1433) of the instance use "localhost:1234".

You can figure out the IP port by looking at the connection string you use to connect to the database via SQL Server Management Studio!

Comment: > library(RSQLServer)
Error : object ‘src_translate_env’ is not exported by 'namespace:dplyr'
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RSQLServer’
> library(DBI)
> drv <- RSQLServer::SQLServer()
Error: object ‘src_translate_env’ is not exported by 'namespace:dplyr'

Comment: I am getting more errors now.  I have spend two days try to debug it. perhaps I will go with RODBC only. I am able to do all these things using RODBC. Thanks a lot Yoda for your help.

Comment: Welcome + good decision, there is no need to use RSQLServer until you have performance problems (e. g. no bulk insert possible or slow updates).